# If I have that $Z$ is a random variable, and $f$ is a measurable function, how can I show that $E(f(Z)Y |Z) = f(Z)E(Y|Z)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

I have that $Z$ is a random variable, and that $f$ a measurable function, and would like to show that:

$$
E(f(Z)Y |Z) = f(Z)E(Y|Z)
$$

This was under wikipedia's expectation page under the "pulling out what is known" section. I am able to do this if I do not use measure theory, but I am unsure how to do this from a measure-theoretic standpoint. Would anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: I think the condition that $f(Z)Y$ is integrable is usually needed. Given this,  you need to check the measure theretic definition of conditional expectation and everything is very obvious from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $X$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable and $\mathbb E[|XY|]<\infty$, then $$\mathbb E[XY\mid Z] = X\mathbb E[Y\mid Z]. \tag 1 $$ The proof uses the "standard machinery" of measure theory - prove $(1)$ for indicator random variables (i.e. $X=\mathsf 1_A$ where $A\in\sigma(Z)$), then for conical combinations of indicator random variaables, then for nonnegative random variables by monotone convergence, then passing to positive and negative parts.

Comment: This is the idea, yes, but one usually mentions functions that are linear combinations of indicator functions between the indicator functions step and the nonnegative functions step.